# JQuery: Closest div that has an ID

Tags: jquery, closest

How would you write the Jquery to get the closest div that actually has an ID defined?

Comment: Define 'closest' in more detail. Child, sibling or parent?

Comment: I imagine that even with the `closest` method being available, the answer to this would be at least 50-100 lines of code if you want to search siblings and children as well.

Comment: sorry, i wanted a parent that is a div and has and id

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You should use [*has attribute* selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/). This sample should do the work:

```
$('selector').closest('[id]')
```

Comment: This looks to ancestors only.  If he wants a sibling or child that's closest as well this won't be enough.

Comment: how does this give me divs with ids as opposed that anything with an id?

Comment: Don't you mean `.closest('div[id]')`?

Answer (score 14):

```
$(elementToStart).parent().closest('div[id]');
```

I use the parent() to avoid just getting the element itself.

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/zQRFT/1/

Comment: this should be the answer, without using parent() mine was not working

Comment: parent().closest() is the same as using parents() which begins with the parent element

Answer (score 11):

Look for an id attribute on a div, using the [closest method](http://api.jquery.com/closest/):

```
$(this).closest('div[id]');
```

The `[id]` brackets there is what's called the [Has Attribute Selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/)