# Select next HTML specific element - jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have this code:

```
<section class="col col-md-4">
<label class="checkbox">                                                       
<input type="checkbox" name="subscription" class="chk_Especialization" value="1">
</label>
</section>  

<section class="col col-md-4">
    <label class="input">
        <input type="text" class="dateRangestart start dateRange" id="start-1" placeholder="dtStart">
    </label>
</section>
<section class="col col-md-4">
    <label class="input">
        <input type="text" class="dateRangefinish finish dateRange" id="finish-1" placeholder="dtEnd">
    </label>
</section>



<section class="col col-md-4">
<label class="checkbox">                                                      
<input type="checkbox" name="subscription" class="chk_Especialization" value="2">
</label>
</section>  

<section class="col col-md-4">
    <label class="input">
        <input type="text" class="dateRangestart start dateRange" id="start-2" placeholder="dtStart">
    </label>
</section>
<section class="col col-md-4">
    <label class="input">
        <input type="text" class="dateRangefinish finish dateRange" id="finish-2" placeholder="dtEnd">
    </label>
</section>


<section class="col col-md-4">
<label class="checkbox">                                                        
<input type="checkbox" name="subscription" class="chk_Especialization" value="3">
</label>
</section>  

<section class="col col-md-4">
    <label class="input">
        <input type="text" class="dateRangestart start dateRange" id="start-3" placeholder="dtStart">
    </label>
</section>
<section class="col col-md-4">
    <label class="input">
        <input type="text" class="dateRangefinish finish dateRange" id="finish-3" placeholder="dtEnd">
    </label>
</section>
```

I want alert id of the next input element if I click over a class start input element, and alert id of the previous input element if I click over a  finish class element.

I have tried use this post [JQuery: Closest div that has an ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096103/jquery-closest-div-that-has-an-id) and this one [jquery, find next element by class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3670136/jquery-find-next-element-by-class) but I think there is some error in my code.

this is the javascript code:

```
$(document).on("click", ".dateRange", function(){
    if($(this).hasClass( "start" )){
        //Select next input element with finish class
        alert($(this).closest('input').next().attr("id"));
    }
    if($(this).hasClass( "finish" )){
        //Select previous input element with start class
        alert($(this).closest('input').prev().attr("id"));
    } 
});
```

I have create a jsfiddle to :http://jsfiddle.net/towx8xro/1/

Any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: Why the slashes in your classes?

Comment: sorry it is becouse I copy from my php code..  I will solve this

Comment: Probably should fix the fiddle too.

Comment: done http://jsfiddle.net/towx8xro/1/

Comment: But it has not changed the final result

Comment: `$(this).closest('input')`??? Read the DOC: http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selector should find the closest `section` element, and then either go forward or backwards to find the related start/end input using `prev` and `next` respectively. Try this:

```
$(document).on("click", ".dateRange", function () {
    var $el = $(this);
    if ($el.hasClass("start")) {
        alert($el.closest('section').next().find('input').prop("id"));
    }
    if ($el.hasClass("finish")) {     
        alert($el.closest('section').prev().find('input').prop("id"));
    }
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/towx8xro/5/)

Answer (score 3):

The problem seems to be you are clicking an `input` then finding the closest `input`, which doesn't work. You need to go up the chain to the `section`, then next or previous and back down to it's input:

```
$(document).on("click", ".dateRange", function(){
    if($(this).hasClass( "start" )){
        //Select next input element with finish class
        alert($(this).closest('section').next().find("input").attr('id'));
    }
    if($(this).hasClass( "finish" )){
        //Select previous input element with start class
        alert($(this).closest('section').prev().find("input").attr('id'));
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.closest()` to determine the `.col` parent of the clicked `input`, then depending on the class the clicked input has `start|finish` determine the `direction` -- `next|prevv`. Use `direction` to select the target `.col` and use `.find` to select the `input` element in the target `.col` and then get it's id.

```
$('.dateRange').on('click',function() {
    var direction = $(this).hasClass( 'start' ) ? 'next' : 'prev';
    alert( $(this).closest('.col')[direction]('.col').find('.dateRange')[0].id );
});
```

```js
$('.dateRange').on('click',function() {
    var direction = $(this).hasClass( 'start' ) ? 'next' : 'prev';
    alert( $(this).closest('.col')[direction]('.col').find('.dateRange')[0].id );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <section class="col col-md-4">
    <label class="checkbox">                                                       
    <input type="checkbox" name="subscription" class="chk_Especialization" value="1">
    </label>
    </section>  

    <section class="col col-md-4">
        <label class="input">
            <input type="text" class="dateRangestart start dateRange" id="start-1" placeholder="dtStart">
        </label>
    </section>
    <section class="col col-md-4">
        <label class="input">
            <input type="text" class="dateRangefinish finish dateRange" id="finish-1" placeholder="dtEnd">
        </label>
    </section>



    <section class="col col-md-4">
    <label class="checkbox">                                                      
    <input type="checkbox" name="subscription" class="chk_Especialization" value="2">
    </label>
    </section>  

    <section class="col col-md-4">
        <label class="input">
            <input type="text" class="dateRangestart start dateRange" id="start-2" placeholder="dtStart">
        </label>
    </section>
    <section class="col col-md-4">
        <label class="input">
            <input type="text" class="dateRangefinish finish dateRange" id="finish-2" placeholder="dtEnd">
        </label>
    </section>


    <section class="col col-md-4">
    <label class="checkbox">                                                        
    <input type="checkbox" name="subscription" class="chk_Especialization" value="3">
    </label>
    </section>  

    <section class="col col-md-4">
        <label class="input">
            <input type="text" class="dateRangestart start dateRange" id="start-3" placeholder="dtStart">
        </label>
    </section>
    <section class="col col-md-4">
        <label class="input">
            <input type="text" class="dateRangefinish finish dateRange" id="finish-3" placeholder="dtEnd">
        </label>
    </section>
```