# Closest Div Id to the element clicked on

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When clicking on a link, I need to find the closest div element that has an id. In the example below, it would be #Inputs or #Stages.

So if I click on Page1 thru 4, I need to have the div id #Inputs saved in a variable. If I click on Page5 thru 8, I need the div id #Stages saved in a variable.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096103/jquery-closest-div-that-has-an-id) and it either does not work or I do not understand what I am getting back.

```
var closestAnchor = $(this).closest('div[id]');
```

Can someone tell me how I can get the div id I need?

```
<tr>
    <td class='type'>
        <div id="#Inputs" class='vertical-text'>
            Inputs
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class='cellData'>
        <div class='links'>
            <span class='sectionLabel'>
                External Input
            </span>
            <div class='openLevelThree'><a id='a1' href='Page1.htm' title='No Tailoring'>Page1</a></div>
            <div class='openLevelThree'><a id='a2' href='Page2.htm' title='No Tailoring'>Page2</a></div>
            <div class='openLevelThree'><a id='a3' href='Page3.htm' title='No Tailoring'>Page3</a></div>
            <div class='openLevelThree'><a id='a4' href='Page4.htm' title='No Tailoring'>Page4</a></div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class='type'>
        <div id="#Stages" class='vertical-text'>
            Stages
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class='cellData'>
        <div class='links'>
            <span class='sectionLabel'>
                External Input
            </span>
            <div class='openLevelThree'><a id='a5' href='Page5.htm' title='No Tailoring'>Page5</a></div>
            <div class='openLevelThree'><a id='a6' href='Page6.htm' title='No Tailoring'>Page6</a></div>
            <div class='openLevelThree'><a id='a7' href='Page7.htm' title='No Tailoring'>Page7</a></div>
            <div class='openLevelThree'><a id='a8' href='Page8.htm' title='No Tailoring'>Page8</a></div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: can you include the JS code your are using when you call that jquery method?

Comment: Your div doesn't have an ID, are you talking about the `<a></a>` tag ID?

Comment: Since all ids are unique, can you not just select the id?

Comment: @AlexBieg I would assume the OP doesn't know the `id` at runtime, hence needs to use DOM traversal. Could be wrong though.

Comment: I thought it had to do with not being the parent, which is why I thought leaving out .parent() would work. thanks for explaining it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you have is that `closest()` goes up the DOM looking for parent elements, yet the `div` you're trying to target isn't a parent, it's a parent's sibling.

To do what you require you could instead use `closest()` to get the nearest `tr`, then use `find()` to get the required `div`. Also note that the `id` attribute values should not contain `#` characters. Try this:

```js
$('.openLevelThree a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  var divId = $(this).closest('tr').find('div[id]').prop('id');
  console.log(divId);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="type">
      <div id="Inputs" class="vertical-text">
        Inputs
      </div>
    </td>
    <td class="cellData">
      <div class="links">
        <span class="sectionLabel">
          External Input
        </span>
        <div class="openLevelThree"><a id="a1" href="Page1.htm" title="No Tailoring">Page1</a></div>
        <div class="openLevelThree"><a id="a2" href="Page2.htm" title="No Tailoring">Page2</a></div>
        <div class="openLevelThree"><a id="a3" href="Page3.htm" title="No Tailoring">Page3</a></div>
        <div class="openLevelThree"><a id="a4" href="Page4.htm" title="No Tailoring">Page4</a></div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="type">
      <div id="Stages" class="vertical-text">
        Stages
      </div>
    </td>
    <td class="cellData">
      <div class="links">
        <span class="sectionLabel">
          External Input
        </span>
        <div class="openLevelThree"><a id="a5" href="Page5.htm" title="No Tailoring">Page5</a></div>
        <div class="openLevelThree"><a id="a6" href="Page6.htm" title="No Tailoring">Page6</a></div>
        <div class="openLevelThree"><a id="a7" href="Page7.htm" title="No Tailoring">Page7</a></div>
        <div class="openLevelThree"><a id="a8" href="Page8.htm" title="No Tailoring">Page8</a></div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```